# Is the convolution pointwise bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces, convolution

A problem from an old exam:

> Prove or disprove: if $p,q \in [1,\infty)$ such that $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$ and $f\in L^p, g\in L^q$, then the convolution $f*g$ is pointwise bounded.

First of all: what did they possibly mean by pointwise boundedness? (As far as I know it's a property of a sequence of functions but $f*g$ is a standalone function).

I know that if $r^{-1}=p^{-1}+q^{-1}-1$ then $\|f*g\|_r \leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$. Can it be used here?

Comment: Read "bounded" for "pointwise bounded". Yes. $r=\infty$. (Also known as Holder's inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
|(f*g)(x)=\int f(x-y)g(y)\, dy| \leq \left( \int |f(x-y)|^p \, dy \right)^{1/p} \left( \int |g(y)|^q \, dy \right)^{1/q} = \|f\|_p \|g\|_q
$$
for (almost) all $x$. Hence $\|f*g\|_\infty \leq$...

Comment: Actually for every $x.$